# Why is there a path to a .pdb file in an exe I am trying to reverse?

Tags: malware, antimalware, reverse-engineering, debugging

My query is ,if I'm  seeing a .pdb path in a exe(VC++) what conclusion  can I draw from it.Why does the exe have these paths and  does it have significance in malware analysis?
eg H:\ConsoleApplication1\Release\ConsoleApplication1.pdb but when the exe will be given to a customer this file will not be present on their H drive,so is this the case of a debug version exe rather than a release version exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .pdb contains information for the compiler. It contains debugging symbols. It also contains names of library's that are used in the application and also names of forms and resources. The reason why you are seeing .pdb path in the exe file is because it was released with debugging turned on. If you got hold of .pdb file it could help you reverse engineer the program.